# Vertical aligining inputs with labels

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I want all my inputs ([image](http://cl.ly/image/453l2y3Z2h17)) aligned at the same vertical line.

Vertical-align css property didn't work and neither did the sass mixin I found (see below).

```
@mixin vertical-align($pos) {
    position: $pos;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Is there an easy way to do it. I've been struggling four half an hour now…

A [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qych4/) including the css & html

Comment: post your actual css and html you tried and if possible provide a demo.

Comment: @NicoO I added a jsfiddle

Comment: your fiddle does not even work... http://jsfiddle.net/qych4/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `vertical-align` property aligns element vertically along the horizontal line. I'm guessing you want all the inputs to start at the same place on the horizontal line creating a kind of two-column grid.

This can be achived by:

```
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 5em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use tables as well! Here is your updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/qych4/5/

formatted your code as well!

```
<section>
        <article>
            <form action="" id="book" method="post" name="book">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Boek</legend>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label>Email:</label></td>
                            <td><input type=""></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label>Tours:</label></td>
                            <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label>Techno</label></td>
                            <td><input type="checkbox"><label>HCore</label>
                            <input type="checkbox"><label>Trance</label></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td><label for="">Aantal pers:</label></td>
                            <td><input type="number"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label>Bericht:</label></td>
                            <td><textarea></textarea></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </article>
    </section>
```